# Javascript this.id to differentiate objects of the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a css class (.SideOption) which has multiple instances on a page and I want to have something to differentiate between them (so I chose ID), but I can't get JS to get the ID, it just returns undefined in the alert box.

JS;

```
function CreateBox()
{
    $MyID = this.id;
    alert($MyID);
}

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".SideOption").click(function() 
    {   
        CreateBox();
    })
})
```

This is what the SideOption looks like for example.

```
<div class="SideOption" id="1">
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".SideOption").click(CreateBox)` or `$(".SideOption").click(function() 
    {   
        CreateBox.call(this);
    })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method to invoke the function with the context of `this` [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/ykcn2etw/)

```
function CreateBox() {
    $MyID = this.id;
    alert($MyID);
}
$(".SideOption").click(function () {
    CreateBox.call(this);
});
```

Alternatively, you could pass a reference to the `CreateBox` function when the element is clicked [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/mjp2kr9x/)

```
function CreateBox() {
    $MyID = this.id;
    alert($MyID);
}

$(".SideOption").click(CreateBox);
```

<sub>(For what it's worth, [a CSS selector cannot begin with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors).)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix your JS like this: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/ajnm3o4m/

Pass the element to `CreateBox` function and then take the attribute "id" with `element.id` or with `$(element).attr("id")`.

```
function CreateBox(element) {
    $MyID = element.id;
    alert($MyID);
}

$(".SideOption").click(function () {
    CreateBox(this);
})
```

Hope it helps!